# There is no error in the code but the button doesn't perform any action

Tags: java, android, validation

I am developing an login and register app. The app is supposed to check if the entered data is correct or not while login or register. The login validation works fine but register doesn't validate data. The register button is supposed to check validations after clicking but nothing happens when I click it. There is no error shown in android studio and the app runs fine.

```
package com.example.investas;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputUsername,inputEmail,inputPassword,inputCpassword;
Button btnRegister;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    TextView btn=findViewById(R.id.alreadyHaveAccount);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView btn=findViewById(R.id.alreadyHaveAccount);
            inputUsername=findViewById(R.id.inputUsername);
            inputEmail=findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
            inputPassword=findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
            inputCpassword=findViewById(R.id.inputCpassword);
            btnRegister=findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    validations();
                }
            });
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
                }
            });
        }
    });

}

 private void validations() {
    String username=inputUsername.getText().toString();
    String email=inputEmail.getText().toString();
    String password=inputPassword.getText().toString();
    String cpassword=inputCpassword.getText().toString();

    if(username.isEmpty() || username.length()<7)
    {
        showError(inputUsername,"Your username is not valid");
    }
    else if(email.isEmpty() || !email.contains("@"))
    {
        showError(inputEmail,"Email is not valid");
    }
    else if(password.isEmpty() || password.length()<7)
    {
        showError(inputPassword,"Password must be 7 characters");
    }
    else if(cpassword.isEmpty() || !cpassword.equals(password))
    {
        showError(inputCpassword,"Passwords are not matching");
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Registration 
Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
 private void showError(EditText input, String your_username_is_not_valid) {
 input.setError(your_username_is_not_valid);
    input.requestFocus();

}
}
```

Comment: `There is no error in the code` there's a difference between runtime issues and compile time issues. while your code might compile, that doesn't mean it does what it should, so yes, there is an error in your code, otherwise you wouldn't be here. how to solve this ? debug it. use breakpoints or logs to see what's happening/what isn't happening. for example, why do you have findViewById statements inside your onClick ?

Comment: why are you making the definitions after the click event is very wrong. And there are 2 nested same btn click events so the sign up button doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to move the following lines out of the `OnClickListener`, they should be in the `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    //...
    inputUsername = findViewById(R.id.inputUsername);
    inputEmail = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
    inputPassword = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
    inputCpassword = findViewById(R.id.inputCpassword);
    btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
               validations();
        }
    });
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be bad if he did it like you? If he makes the definitions in the button, if he tries to use those definitions again, he will go to code repetition.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked. I am new to coding so  I could not understand this silly mistake: :)

Answer (score 0):

Doing it this way is necessary for it to be cleaner and to work.

```
private EditText inputUsername,inputEmail,inputPassword,inputCpassword;
Button btnRegister;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
            TextView btn=findViewById(R.id.alreadyHaveAccount);
            inputUsername=findViewById(R.id.inputUsername);
            inputEmail=findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
            inputPassword=findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
            inputCpassword=findViewById(R.id.inputCpassword);
            btnRegister=findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    TextView btn=findViewById(R.id.alreadyHaveAccount);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {                                
              startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
                
        }
    });

    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
               validations();
        }
    });

}
```